# Is this valid css

Tags: html, css

Is this CSS style valid because I have never seen the *

```
*html .boxTop {margin-bottom:-2px;}
```

and if it is valid how does it differ from

```
html .boxTop {margin-bottom:-2px;}
```

Comment: Its not valid CSS but an IE hack.

Comment: It is NOT a hack. It is a wildcard.

Answer (score 4):

I believe that is an Internet Explorer CSS hack. Specifically, it targets IE6 and below. See

http://paulirish.com/2009/browser-specific-css-hacks/

Comment: and as Chris Smith pointed out, this is a failed attempted at said hack ;)

Answer (score 2):

Well, "*" is known as Universal selector. The universal selector, matches the name of any element type. It matches any single element in the document tree.

*html { ... } should be equivalent to html { ... }

Check this link for more details
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#universal-selector

Answer (score 1):

The `*` simply selected all elements. It's valid but unnecessary. The first is essentially saying, "In all `html` tags, target `.boxTop`", while the second targets only the `html` element(which there should only be one of anyways). You might as well just use `.boxTop {margin-bottom:-2px;}` because it'd be the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid code (a typo).  It's a bad attempt at a star hack "* html" which targets the rule against certain browsers.  More information here:

http://www.dynamicsitesolutions.com/css/filters/star-html/

Answer (score 0):

The `*` sign, in CSS, refer to all elements.

In this case I guess that it refer to all the elements in the HTML code.

I think is the same of `* .boxTop`